# Calculating $n$ mod $m$ given the prime factorization of $n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Say I have the prime factorization of a large integer $n$. 
$$n=p_1^{a_{1}}\cdot p_2^{a_{2}}\ldots p_k^{a_{k}}$$
However, I do not have $n$ itself.

How do I calculate $n$ mod $m$, given only $n$'s prime factorization and the mod $m$, **without** factoring $n$ (if it's efficiently possible at all)?

Comment: You can find $p \pmod{m}$ for every prime and then put them together to get $n \pmod{m}$ .

Comment: Perhaps the (computationally) easiest thing to do is compute $p^{\omega} \pmod m$ for each $p$ (say, by successive squaring), and then multiply the remainders.

Comment: What do you mean "without factoring n"? The product *is* the factorization of $n$.

Comment: I mean I don't wanna find $n$ itself. I can find its prime factorization through different criteria, but I don't want to find it itself. And thus only finding $n$ mod $m$ through its prime factorization.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly your data are? Also, $\omega$ depends on $p$, right?

Comment: It's irrelevant. I'm given $n$'s prime factorization. Now, I want to calculate $n$ mod $m$ only using $n$'s prime factorization, without factoring $n$ itself. @AndreasCaranti

Comment: "without factoring $n$".  People are confused because *you have already factored $n$*.  What you are trying to say is "without multiplying the factors in $\mathbb{Z}$ to get $n$".  'To factor' means 'to split into prime factors'.  You already have that.

Answer (score 1):

Find ${p^w} \pmod m$ for all $p$ from the prime factorization of n.
Then multiply these values and take modulo m
(btw, you'd better take modulo m as you multiply).

Comment: Why is this faster than simply multiplying all the factors together, reducing $\bmod m$ as you go? While it is certainly possible to compute $p^w \bmod m$ more efficiently than just multiplying $p$ by itself $w$ times (and reducing $\bmod m$ as you go), you haven't mentioned this in your answer.

Comment: Two other possible optimizations: if the exponents are gigantic there may be an improvement from factoring $m$ first and reducing them with Euler's theorem.  Also, if we first sort the primes by their exponents, group like exponents together, and look at the divisibility graph, we can reduce the number of multiplications, i.e. $3^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 13^4 \cdot 17^5 = (3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13^2)^2 \cdot 17^5$, but I'm not sure in what cases this would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

$n \equiv p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}... \pmod{m}$

$p_1 \equiv c \pmod{m}\implies p_1^{a_1}\equiv c^{a_1} \pmod {m}$

$a^{p_1-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {p_1}$

$gcd(a,m)=1, a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod {m}$.

---

Example
$n=3^{55}5^{77}29^{23}, m=34 $

$\phi(34)=16$

$n\equiv 3^{3\cdot 16 + 7} \cdot 5^{2\cdot 34+9}\cdot(-5)^{16+7}\pmod{34}= 3^7\cdot 5^9\cdot(-1)\cdot5^7 \pmod{34} \equiv -3^8 $

$\equiv (-1)(3^4)^2 \pmod{34} \equiv (-1)(81^2)\pmod{34}\equiv (-1)(13^2)\pmod{34}\equiv 33$

I don't know what $n$ is, but it's congruent to 33 modulo 34.

Comment: I think you meant $n\equiv 3^{3\cdot 16 + 7} \cdot \color{red}{5^{4\cdot 16+13}}\cdot(-5)^{16+7}\pmod{34}= 3^7\cdot \color{red}{5^{13}}\cdot(-1)\cdot5^7 \pmod{34} \equiv \color{red}{-3^7 \cdot 5^{13 \cdot 7}}$.  (The beauty of math software).  Otherwise very efficient, +1!